# Block ios app internationalization

Tags: ios, localization, fscalendar

I am facing a problem with the internationalization of my app. The calendar that I m using in my app (FSCalendar) is returning me values in Greek. My localizations are turned off and my storyboard is set to Base.
I want my app to be strictly in English. Is there any way I can get rid of internationalization?

Comment: The calendar probably uses `NSDateFormatter`. That in turn formats dates (by default) based on the current locale (from `NSLocale`). There is no API to force a specific default `NSLocale`.